# How to filter a collection in elasticsearch document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a data model which designed before i started development. Model has a collection of key value pair(an it is in a nested object). And i am trying to filter specific keys on this collection like below:

```
{
   "created":"2015-09-07",
   "collection":[
      {
         "key":"a",
         "value":12
      },
      {
         "key":"b",
         "value":21
      },
      {
         "key":"c",
         "value":36
      }
   ]
}
```

For Example: i am trying to get sum of values which its key is "a",
I tried a query like below

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "allMembers": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "doc.collection.key": "a"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "rev": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "doc.collection.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {}
}
```

this query returns sum of all values in every document.

I think it is normal and there is no way of doing this with current data model. I searched for similar cases but i could not find any. I think ElasticSearch is not meant to do this. But other team members did not believe that.

I think maybe i should do it in the program, get entire document cast in an another object and get sum of collection with a query. But in this case why should i use the elasticsearch i can do it with using a nosql database or redis.

Can script field in the sum aggregator help me?
Are there any way of doing this in elasticsearch with current data model? 
Or should i do it on the program?

Mapping of the document

```
{
"smyrna": {
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_source": {
                "includes": [
                    "meta.*"
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "meta": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "include_in_all": false
                }
            }
        },
        "couchbaseDocument": {
            "_source": {
                "includes": [
                    "meta.*",
                    "doc.*"
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "doc": {
                    "properties": {
                        "body": {
                            "properties": {
                                "data": {
                                    "type": "nested",
                                    "properties": {

                                        "products": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "categories": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "categoryId": {
                                                            "type": "long"
                                                        },
                                                        "categoryName": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "currency": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "endQuantity": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                },
                                                "itemCode": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "modelCode": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                },
                                                "modelName": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                                                },
                                                "name": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "quantity": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                },
                                                "totalPrice": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                },
                                                "trademark": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "manufacturerName": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "trademarkName": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "unitPrice": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },

                                        "totalAmount": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        },
                                        "uri": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "userId": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "created": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                        },
                        "header": {
                            "properties": {
                                "appKey": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "channel": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "client": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "new in 2.0": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ownerAge": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Actually I am trying to calculate sum of totalPrice for every modelCode

Comment: Can you please share the mapping of your index in which these documents are indexed? You can retrieve it by the command `GET _mapping`.

Comment: i added my mapping to question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explicitly define the mapping before storing documents.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "couchbaseDocument": {
      "properties": {
        "created": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "collection": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Actually I am trying to calculate sum of totalPrice for every
>   modelCode

Assuming `modelCode` is `collection`'s `key`, this [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) gives you the results:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "collection": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "collection"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "keys": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "collection.key",
            "order": {
              "value_sum": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "value_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "collection.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An example response:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "collection": {
            "doc_count": 7,
            "keys": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "c",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "value_sum": {
                            "value": 79
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "a",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "value_sum": {
                            "value": 46
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "b",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "value_sum": {
                            "value": 21
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "f",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "value_sum": {
                            "value": 20
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```